# Seperate XML content from a string using Perl regular expression

Tags: xml, regex, perl

I have the below string which contains text seperated by (\n). I want to match the xml content using regular expressions, remove all the whitespace and \n and convert it into a single line. I used the following regular expression:

```
my $string = "this contains the text which I pasted below in before section";
$string=~ m/(^.*)(<[a-zA-Z]*>)/;
$extractedXml = $2;
```

Why does the above code not get the XML content?

**Before:**

```
G11N/Locale=en_USY:/default/main/test1/test/test2/test4/test5/default.site
G11N/Localizable=true
TeamSite/Assocation/Version=1
TeamSite/LiveSite/DeploymentAudit=<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Deployments>
    <test>hello</test>
</Deployments>
```

**After:**

```
Y:/default/main/test1/test/test2/test4/test5/default.site
G11N/Locale=en_US
G11N/Localizable=true
TeamSite/Assocation/Version=1
TeamSite/LiveSite/DeploymentAudit=<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?><Deployments><test>hello</test></Deployments>
```

**http://regex101.com/r/zZ0wB8** 
You can check that it works here, but in the actual code it matches only the first line.

Comment: Your regex does not match your text at all. See http://regex101.com/r/pO5nW7. If you add a `/m` modifier, it will at least match the first tag `<Deployments>`. It cannot however match the `<?xml>` or any of the closing tags as you have allowed anything else but letters.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For your example, the following solution works:

```
my $string = <<"FOO";
G11N/Locale=en_USY:/default/main/test1/test/test2/test4/test5/default.site
G11N/Localizable=true
TeamSite/Assocation/Version=1
TeamSite/LiveSite/DeploymentAudit=<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Deployments>
    <test>hello</test>
</Deployments>";
FOO

$string =~ s/^\s+(<.+$)/$1/gm;
$string =~ s/>\n/>/gm;

print $string;
```

It will first remove whitespace from any line that starts with something that looks like an xml tag and whitespace and after that get rid of the newline characters at the end of any line that ends with what might be the end of an xml tag.

This is a very pragmatic approach that will most likely not work in all the cases. It only works for unix files because of the `\n`.

Comment: http://regex101.com/r/zZ0wB8

check this it works here but in the actual code it matches only firstline

Comment: In that case, tell us.

Answer (score 0):

You could use this:

```
my ($xml) = $string =~ m!(<Deployments>.*?</Deployments>)!gis;
```

Regards.

Comment: xml can be anything not only starting with deployment

Comment: http://regex101.com/r/zZ0wB8 check this it works here but in the actual code it matches only firstline